# Why doesn't this CSS show my background images?

Tags: css

Very odd. This CSS isn't displaying the background images at all. I don't see anything wrong with it. I tried it with the full path to the image, still no result.

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(wp-content/uploads/2021/11/bg-patter-side-right2x.png), url(wp-content/uploads/2021/11/bg-pattern-side-left2x.png);
background-position: 100% -69%, -10% -10%;
background-attachment: fixed!;
```

}

Edit: I found that the Divi theme was putting white in the container as a background. I made that background transparent and now both backgrounds show up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any content, and if not: Did you define `height: 100%` for `body` and `html`? (If the answer is no to both questions, body has 0 height, so you wouldn't see any background)

Comment: I added the following, but there was no change.

html, body {
  height:100%!important;
}

Comment: Try height: 100vh; and open console developer tool to see if there is unfined error.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your URLs in quotations

```
   body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('wp-content/uploads/2021/11/bg-patter-side-right2x.png'), url('wp-content/uploads/2021/11/bg-pattern-side-left2x.png');
    background-position: 100% -69%, -10% -10%;
    background-attachment: fixed!;
    }
```

Comment: Yep. I tried ' and " but nothing changed.